# What does this selector selects: $('[Id*=txtSomeInput]')?

Tags: jquery, css

Actually I am trying to udnerstand the universal selector gives what meaning to this jQuery selector:

```
$('[Id*=txtCreatedDateTo]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) , and you need the quotes.

It selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

Answer (score 1):

all elements which has an `Id` attribute whose value *contains* the string *txtCreatedDateTo*

Answer (score 1):

This selector selects all the elements in which the `Id` attribute contains "`txtCreatedDateTo`":

http://jqapi.com/#p=attribute-contains-selector